# PHP PDO Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() : Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am using PHP and PDO with prepared statements in a class file.  I keep getting the error: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() : Access denied for user. When the method is called.  I really do not know how to get around this problem.

Here is the method from the class file:

```
public function insertReview() {
    $fk_employee = $_POST['fk_employee'];

    // Current Date returned from JQuery and formatted to add to DB.
    $cdate = $_POST['current_date'];
    $current_date = explode("/", $cdate);
      $cmonth = $current_date[0];
      $cday = $current_date[1];
      $cyear = $current_date[2];
      $current_dateA = array($cyear, $cmonth, $cday);
    $review_date = implode("-", $current_dateA);

    // Review Begin Date returned from JQuery Datepicker and formatted to add to DB.              
    $bdate = $_POST['r_period_begin'];
    $begin_date = explode("/", $bdate);
      $bmonth = $begin_date[0];
      $bday = $begin_date[1];
      $byear = $begin_date[2];
      $begin_dateA = array($byear, $bmonth, $bday);
    $r_period_begin = implode("-", $begin_dateA);

    // Review End Date returned from JQuery Datepicker and formatted to add to DB.
    $edate = $_POST['r_period_end'];
    $end_date = explode("/", $edate);
      $emonth = $end_date[0];
      $eday = $end_date[1];
      $eyear = $end_date[2];
      $end_dateA = array($eyear, $emonth, $eday);
    $r_period_end = implode("-", $end_dateA);

    // Criteria 
      $criterias = $_POST['criteria'];
      $criteriaValue = $_POST['criteriaValue'];
      $comments = $_POST['Comments'];

      foreach ($criteriaValue as $key => $value ){
          foreach( $criterias as $crit ){
              if( $crit == $key ){
                  $string1 = $key;
                  foreach( $comments as $comment => $comm ){
                      if( $string1 == $comment ){
                          $string3 = $comm;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          foreach ( $value as $result ){
              $string2 = $result;
          }

      $criteria .= mysql_real_escape_string( $string1 . '|' . $string2 . '|' . $string3 . '|' );
      }

    $overall_rating = $_POST['overall_rating'];
    $additional_comments = $_POST['additional_comments'];
    $goals = $_POST['goals'];

  $conn = parent::connect();
  $sql = "INSERT INTO " . TBL_EMPLOYEE_REVIEW . " (
            fk_employee,
            review_date,
            r_period_begin,
            r_period_end,
            criteria,
            overall_rating,
            additional_comments,
            goals  
          ) VALUES (
            :fk_employee,
            :review_date,
            :r_period_begin,
            :r_period_end,
            :criteria,
            :overall_rating,
            :additional_comments,
            :goals
          )";

  try {
    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":fk_employee", $fk_employee, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":review_date", $review_date, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":r_period_begin", $r_period_begin, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":r_period_end", $r_period_end, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":criteria", quote($criteria), PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":overall_rating", $overall_rating, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":additional_comments", $additional_comments, PDO::PARAM_STR );
    $st->bindValue( ":goals", $goals, PDO::PARAM_STR );

    $st->execute();
    parent::disconnect( $conn );
  } catch ( PDOException $e ) {
            echo $e->getFile();
            echo $e->getTraceAsString();
            echo "The exception was created on line: " . $e->getLine();

    die( "Query failed: " . $e->getMessage() );
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need `mysql_real_escape_string()` with PDO methods.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `mysql_real_escape_string()` when using PDO.  The PDO class handles the escaping itself.

Everytime you use the `bindValue()`,  It's doing it for you.

Replace this line:

```
$criteria .= mysql_real_escape_string( $string1 . '|' . $string2 . '|' . $string3 . '|' );
```

With this line:

```
$criteria .=  $string1 . '|' . $string2 . '|' . $string3 . '|';
```

Comment: if I take out the mysql_real_escape_string that part of the code stops working.  I don't know how to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

PDO and `mysql_*` are two entirely different extensions. `mysql_real_escape_string` needs a database connection to do its job. If you did not establish a connection using `mysql_connect` before, `mysql_real_escape_string` will try to create a new connection using default credentials when you call it. This fails, hence the error message.

As @Shackrock said, don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` if you're not using `mysql_*`. Use PDO's escaping functions, more precisely PDO's parameterized queries and bound values. That's a lot better than manual escaping anyway.